# Do you have to move backwards with a 10 in Sorry?

Tags: sorry

If you are unable to move forward when drawing a 10, do you have to move backwards 1?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**,

From the rules are on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorry!_%28game%29#Rules).

> **10** - Move a pawn 10 spaces forward or 1 space backward. If a player cannot go forward ten spaces, he **must** go back one space.

Comment: Also, as discussed [here](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/4172/1140), "... if at any time you can move, you must move, even if it's to your disadvantage." (Hasbro also has a scanned copy of the rules [here](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/sorry.pdf) on their site ... note that Wikipedia essentially clarifies these rules.)